# WPF DataTemplate with ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, listbox

I have a very complex DataTemplate which contains three listbox, where they all have a data template for their own and a style for grouping

I'm getting an exception:
    {"Cannot find resource named 'ContainerStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."}

```
 <Window.Resources>



    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>                
            <!-- 
            Merge in the resource dictionary that is shared between the main window and the overview window.
            -->
            <ResourceDictionary 
                Source="SharedVisualTemplates.xaml"
                />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MessagesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Message">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="IncludesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Include">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefinitionsDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Definition">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="InterfacesDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Interface">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" MouseLeftButtonDown="interface_mouseDown">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Focusable="True">

                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="16" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400"/>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="400">
                                <Run Text="IsMulticast: " FontSize="14" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding IsMultiCast}" FontSize="14"/>

                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTip>
                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="4"
                                Name="lbMessages"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding MessagesView}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessagesDataTemplate}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    </ListBox>

                    <ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="4"
                                Name="lbIncludes"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding IncludesView}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IncludesDataTemplate}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    </ListBox>

                    <ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="4"
                                Name="lbDefinitions"  Background="Transparent"  ItemsSource="{Binding DefinitionsView}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefinitionsDataTemplate}" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}"/>
                        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumsDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Enum">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"   MouseLeftButtonDown="enum_mouseDown"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="StructsDataTemplate"
              DataType="ca:Struct">
            <Grid>
              <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  MouseLeftButtonDown="struct_mouseDown"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- UI commands. -->

        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteSelectedNodes" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.CreateNode" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteNode" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.DeleteConnection" />            
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.ZoomOut" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.ZoomIn" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.JumpBackToPrevZoom" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.FitContent" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.Fill" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Commands.OneHundredPercent" />

        <!-- 
        This converts from a scale value to a percentage value.
        It is used to convert the value of 'ContentScale' to the percentage zoom level that is displayed in the UI.
        -->
        <con:ScaleToPercentConverter 
            x:Key="scaleToPercentConverter" 
            />


        <!-- 
        Define the visual style for a 'ConnectorItem'.
        -->
        <Style 
            TargetType="{x:Type NetworkUI:ConnectorItem}"
            >
            <!-- 
            Data-binding for the connector hotspot.
            ConnectorItem automatically computes its center points and assings this value
            to the 'Hotspot' property.  This data-binding then 'pushes' the value into the application
            view-model.
            -->
            <Setter 
                Property="Hotspot"
                Value="{Binding Hotspot, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                />

            <!-- The visual template. -->
            <Setter 
                Property="Template"
                >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate 
                        TargetType="{x:Type NetworkUI:ConnectorItem}"
                        >
                        <!-- The visual for the connector. -->
                        <Ellipse
                            Stroke="{StaticResource nodeBorderBrush}"
                            Fill="{StaticResource connectorBackgroundBrush}"
                            />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--Style For MainListBox-->
        <Style x:Key="ContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" IsExpanded="False">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Where is the `ContainerStyle` declared? it should be in a location that's reachable by the `StaticResource` Extension.

Comment: I will now edit the message so you can see the whole code

Answer (score 2):

StaticResource requires that the referenced resource name be in scope ahead of the usage at load time. Can't tell here but if you have ContainerStyle declared later in the file than your templates that would cause this error. If not there are a lot of other possible ways this could be setup that would cause it to not be in scope yet, in which case you could try using DynamicResource instead.

Comment: The ContainerStyle resource is declared after the DataTemplate, i will edit the post with the whole code. I tried DynamicResource and it still threw an exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Yogevnn the "ContainerStyle" is declared at the end -- it has to be declared before all references to it.